# UIManagedDocument saveToURL completionHandler is not called - Error message: "The reader is not permitted to access the URL."

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, uimanageddocument

I've got an old app that uses `UIManagedDocument` to interact with Core Data. However on iOS 11.2 (and possibly earlier iOS 11 point releases) the `saveToURL:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:` method seems to have stopped working both on-device and in the simulator (however it *does* still work in the iOS 10.3.1 simulator). Specifically, in the code below the `completionHandler` inside the first `if` statement is never executed (as `NSLog` messages indicate).

```
- (void)useDemoDocument {
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TWL_Document"];
    UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]) {
        NSLog(@"This Code Executes");
        [document saveToURL:url
           forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
          completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
              if (success) {
                  NSLog(@"But this is never called");
                  self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
              } else {
                  NSLog(@"This also is not called");
              }
          }];
    } else if (document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
                self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
            }
        }];
    } else {
        self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Instead I get an error message that `The reader is not permitted to access the URL.`:

```
2017-12-17 12:38:14.258936-0800 ToWatchList[1864:542434] [default] [ERROR] Could not get attribute values for item /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2[UUID]/Documents/TWL_Document (n). Error: Error Domain=NSFileProviderInternalErrorDomain Code=1 "The reader is not permitted to access the URL." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The reader is not permitted to access the URL.}
```

What's going on here? Any suggestions on how to get this working again in iOS 11?

Comment: I have encountered the very same error but with `UIDocument`. However, it continues to successfully save after the error. See my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049671/uidocument-creation-on-ios-11-reader-is-not-permitted-to-access-the-url

Comment: Thanks @HuaTham it seems to be working as you describe: continuing to save after the error. (Other errors were causing related failures when I wrote the question a few weeks ago).

Leaving the question up for now in hopes there's a fix in iOS 11.3 or iOS 12 because it's still a bad/weird error.

Comment: Having a similar problem. although in my case the thread opening the doc just gets stuck. I have seen an a "permission" problem error once or twice but not consistent (all on device). Only resetting the device completely allows a successful save of a new file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369571/uimanageddocuemnt-wont-open