# UIManagedDocuemnt won't open

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My app (Xcode 9.2, Swift 4) uses UIManagedDocument as a basic Core Data stack. Everything was working fine for months but lately I've noticed several cases where the app won't load for existing users because the core data init isn't completing. This usually happens after a crash in the app (I think but not sure).

I've been able to recreate the problem on the debugger and narrowed the problem down to the following scenario:

App starts up --> core data is called to start up --> UIManagedDocument object is init'd --> check doc status == closed --> call open() on doc --> open never completes - the callback closure is never called.

I've subclassed UIManagedDocument so I could override `configurePersistentStoreCoordinator()` to check if it ever reaches that point but it doesn't. The subclass override for `handleError()` is never called either.

The `open()` process never reaches that point. What I can see if I pause the debugger is that a couple of threads are blocked on mutex/semaphore related to the open procedure:
[image]
[image]

The 2nd thread (11) seems to be handling some kind of file conflict but I can't understand what and why. When I check `documentState` just before opening the file I can see its value is `[.normal, .closed]`

This is the code to init the doc - pretty straight forward and works as expected for most uses and use cases:

```
class MyDataManager {

static var sharedInstance = MyDataManager()

var managedDoc : UIManagedDocument!
var docUrl : URL!

var managedObjContext : NSManagedObjectContext {
    return managedDoc.managedObjectContext
}

func configureCoreData(forUser: String, completion: @escaping (Bool)->Void) {

    let dir = UserProfile.profile.getDocumentsDirectory()
    docUrl = dir.appendingPathComponent(forUser + GlobalDataDocUrl, isDirectory: true)

    managedDoc = UIManagedDocument(fileURL: docUrl)

    //allow the UIManagedDoc to perform lieghtweight migration of the DB in case of small changes in the model
    managedDoc.persistentStoreOptions = [
        NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true
    ]


    switch (self.managedDoc.documentState)
    {
    case UIDocumentState.normal:
        DDLogInfo("ManagedDocument is ready \(self.docUrl)")
    case UIDocumentState.closed:
        DDLogInfo("ManagedDocument is closed - will open it")
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: self.docUrl.path) {
            self.managedDoc.open() { [unowned self] (success) in
                DDLogInfo("ManagedDocument is open result=\(success)")
                completion(success)
            }
        }
        else{
            self.managedDoc.save(to: self.managedDoc.fileURL, for: .forCreating) { [unowned self]  (success) in
                DDLogInfo("ManagedDocument created result=\(success) ")
                completion(success)
            }

        }
    case UIDocumentState.editingDisabled:
        fallthrough
    case UIDocumentState.inConflict:
        fallthrough
    case UIDocumentState.progressAvailable:
        fallthrough
    case UIDocumentState.savingError:
        fallthrough
    default:
        DDLogWarn("ManagedDocument status is  \(self.managedDoc.documentState.rawValue)")
    }
}
}
```

Again - the closure callback for `managedDoc.open()` never gets called. It seems like the file was left in some kind of bad state and cannot be opened. 
BTW, if I copy the app container from the device to my mac and open the SQLLite store I can see everything is there as expected.